# Juju vault causing problems when deploying openstack/base on maas and charmed-kubernetes

Tags: openstack, hashicorp-vault, juju, charmed-kubernetes

I have deployed openstack/base on MaaS as indicated [here](https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#cluster-deployment). After I tried to deploy charmed-kubernetes with an openstack-integrator and vault overlay, I cannot perform openstackclient commands on the maas node and the images uploaded to the dashboard are not recognized, that means, the ubuntu charms cannot be deployed. When I do, for example,

> openstack catalog list

I get

> Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting https://keystone_ip:5000/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL.
>   SSL exception connecting to https://keystone_ip:5000/v3/auth/tokens: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='keystone_ip', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

However, when I ssh into the keystone container, there is a keystone_juju_ca_cert.crt which has as

> Issuer: CN = Vault Root Certificate Authority (charm-pki-local)

and as

> Subject: CN = Vault Root Certificate Authority (charm-pki-local)

I have also tried to reissue the certificates and refresh the secrets through actions in the vault application, but to no avail.

Can somobody help me here ?

Comment: I don't know anything about juju or openstack, but it looks to me like the problem isn't on the keystone container, but on your local machine (or wherever you are running this `openstack catalog list` command. The local machine doesn't appear to have the `charm-pki-local` CA certificate installed, so it can't verify the connection to the keystone server.

Comment: That's it. I cannot believe the vault charm does not do this automatically. If you propose it as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about juju or openstack, but it looks to me like the problem isn't on the keystone container, but on your local machine (or wherever you are running this `openstack catalog list` command. The local machine doesn't appear to have the `charm-pki-local` CA certificate installed, so it can't verify the connection to the keystone server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get root ca from vault using juju and then reference that file in openrc file as OS_CACERT environment variable